# vuetifyjs v-simple-table - change the loading status of the button on click

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a vuetifyjs v-simple-table. I am doing v-for to populate some data. I have a button in every row. When I click on the button, it should show the loading status (the clicked button). I have the following code

```
<v-simple-table>
   <template v-slot:default>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>
               Status
            </th>
            <th class="text-left">
               Actions
            </th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr v-for="(item, index) in parcels" v-bind:key="index" :class="item.order.bgColorClass">
            <td>
               <div class="status">
                  <span class="a-blue">Notified </span>
                  <v-icon>mdi-star</v-icon>
               </div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <v-btn  :ref="item.order.orderId" :loading="false" text class="table-btn" @click="AddItem(item.order.orderId)">
                  <v-img src="images/plus-i.svg"></v-img>
               </v-btn>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </template>
</v-simple-table>
```

The method is

```
  methods:{  
     AddItem(orderId) {
        this.$refs[orderId][0].loading = true;
     },
```

The above method shows the loader but this is not the correct way I guess. I am getting the following error on console

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be
> overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a
> data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being
> mutated: "loading"

How can I change the loading status of the button when I click on it in a proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take that button and wrap it, e.g:

```js
{
  name: "wrapped-v-btn",
  data(){
    return {
      loading: false
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <v-btn  
    :loading="loading" 
    @click="loading=!loading"
    v-bind="$attrs"
  >
    <v-img src="images/plus-i.svg"></v-img>
  </v-btn>
</template>


...
<td>
  <wrapped-v-btn text class="table-btn" />
</td>
```